# How click events work on disabled input field in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a disabled input tag in which the cursor property is text;

```
<input type="text" value='1111' style='cursor:text' disabled>
```

When I click on that input I want the disabled attribute to be removed. but things seems doesn't work.

```
input.addEventListener('click', function () {
input.disabled = false})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the `<input>` in another element and bind the event to that. Add CSS property `pointer-events: none` to `<input>` so that the `<label>` is the only element recognizing the click, or mouse event (see Kaiido's comments).

```js
document.querySelector('label').onclick = e => {
  const input = e.currentTarget.firstElementChild;
  input.disabled = false;
  input.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
}
```

```html
<label style='cursor: not-allowed'>
  <input type='text' style='cursor: text; pointer-events: none' value='Click to enable' disabled>
</label>
```

Comment: Is this working anywhere? The click event on the <input> should be stopped and thus the should never bubble up the <label>. You should have to click outside of the <input> to receive the bubbling event. That's what happens on my FF and Chrome on macOS.

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73160594/how-click-events-work-on-disabled-input-field-in-javascript#comment129210790_73160651 This solution doesn't work in Firefox, nor in Chrome with some flags and it shouldn't work per specs. For the cursor, you should be able to set it on the label, when the input isn't disabled it will win: https://jsfiddle.net/72re9zLn/

Answer (score 2):

> How do click events work on disabled input field in javascript?

The [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#enabling-and-disabling-form-controls:-the-disabled-attribute) says:

> A form control that is [disabled](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-fe-disabled) must prevent any `click` events that are [queued](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#queue-a-task) on the [user interaction task source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#user-interaction-task-source) from being dispatched on the element.

Because the disabled element isn't receiving the `click` event, you can wrap it in an element and add a `click` event listener to that wrapper instead:

> Note that ([as Kaiido pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73160594/how-click-events-work-on-disabled-input-field-in-javascript#comment129210790_73160651)), disabling pointer events on disabled elements is required to make this work according to spec, using the style declaration `[disabled] { pointer-events: none; }`

```css
[disabled] { pointer-events: none; }
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="text" value='1111' disabled />
</label>

<script type="module">

const label = document.querySelector('label');
const input = label.querySelector(':scope > input');

label.addEventListener('click', () => {
  input.disabled = false;
  input.focus();
});

</script>
```

Comment: Is this working anywhere? The click event on the <input> should be stopped and thus the should never bubble up the <label>. You should have to click outside of the <input> to receive the bubbling event. That's what happens on my FF and Chrome on macOS.

Comment: @Kaiido Can you elaborate? The [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#labeled-control) states that activation behavior for labelled controls is platform-defined.

Comment: No it states "The activation behavior of a label element for events targeted at interactive content descendants of a label element, and any descendants of those interactive content descendants, must be to do nothing." The <input> in that case is an interactive content descendant of the label element, thus the click on the label should be ignored, so that the input receives it. At receiving of this event the input should cancel the click event since it's disabled. Can you confirm that your snippet does work for you? And if so, please could you share your config?

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, it reproduces: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bevrk.gif I'm using Chrome `103.0.5060.134` (macOS)

Comment: Ok, that's basically https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/2368 And the one bit about my Chrome is that I had the "Experimental Web Platform features" flag on (spotted thanks to [this comment](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/2368#issuecomment-989871596)). This anyway doesn't work in Firefox, stable without funky flags, and this doesn't adhere to HTML specs, so I don't think it's a good idea to advocate this idea. One workaround that should make it work everywhere correctly is to add a `[disabled] { pointer-events: none }`.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for sharing that tracking issue. I updated the answer. Can you confirm that it works for you now?

Comment: Yes it does work